# Error in simple java code

Tags: java

I'm studying about Linear Regression and I want implement it. I want get information about Linear Regression data in "data.txt" text file. I use `Scanner` class for read a file. And I also want put them in class variables. When I use 'for loop' to put them variable, I encounter Error.

Here is error information

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at linearregression.LinearRegression.initFile(LinearRegression.java:35)
35 line is `y[i]=scan.nextInt();`
```

and the code is

```
    private final double LEARNING_RATE=0.0001;

    private int num_TrainingSet;
    private int num_Features;

    private int[][] x;
    private int[] y;
    private double[] theta;

    private Scanner scan;

    public LinearRegression()
    {
        x = new int[num_TrainingSet][num_Features];
        y = new int[num_TrainingSet];
        theta = new double[num_Features+1];
    }

    public void initFile() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("src/linearregression/data.txt");
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        num_TrainingSet = scan.nextInt();
        num_Features = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<num_TrainingSet;i++)
        {
            y[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

and when i also changes this code `y[i]=scan.nextInt()` to `y[i]=0`; , also encounters Error.

Comment: when an app asks you to enter a number of records of the training set did you insert 0 ?

Comment: Your title is not useful. Please edit it to reflect the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor allocates the memory for the x and y arrays:

```
    x = new int[num_TrainingSet][num_Features];
    y = new int[num_TrainingSet];
```

But at this point, `num_TrainingSet` and `num_Features` are both 0 since you haven't actually initialized those variables.  So the arrays you allocated in the constructor are both of zero-length.

Instead, allocate the arrays in your `initFile` method, after the user has given his input.

```
    num_TrainingSet = scan.nextInt();
    num_Features = scan.nextInt();
    x = new int[num_TrainingSet][num_Features];
    y = new int[num_TrainingSet];
```

Comment: thanks a lot  i understand what i mistake. it works after changing